# Method on Parse.com framework not being found by XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I installed the Parse iOS api version 1.7.4 and ParseUI version 1.1.4 using Cocoapods.

I am using the PFQueryTableViewController class in XCode in order to display the items on a Parse.com app database. I want to call the "loadObjects" method, but the autocomplete tells me the method can't be found and does not allow me to compile the app.

If I manually go to the ParseUI framework, at the PFQueryTableViewController.h header file, the method loadObjects is there. And I can use the other methods from this class.

So why can't Xcode find it?

I tried creating a new project from scratch and installing the frameworks again but didn't have any luck.

Thanks!

Edit: This is a sample code which doesn't work, from the project I created from scratch.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI


class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func updateUI() {
        loadObjects() // <- This line has an exclamation mark on Xcode. Autocomplete does not show this method.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try importing the header?

Comment: Hi Krukusa. Yes, I imported the header. The other methods on the PFQueryTableViewController work fine, it is just this elusive loadObjects that does not work... :-(

Comment: Did you try self.loadObjects()?
if it isn't that I can guarantee you that you aren't importing correctly even if you installed it through cocoapods.

Comment: Doesn't work either... But if I am not importing correctly how's that the other methods work? For example loadNextPage() appears correctly on autocomplete and works as it should...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was the problem.

The loadObjects method signature in the ParseUI framework is:

```
- (BFTask *)loadObjects;
```

Because of that (BFTask *) return type, I had to manually import the Bolts framework at the top of my code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Bolts
```

Anyway, this feels like a workaround. It shouldn't be necessary to manually import every framework used by the frameworks I am using in my project. :-(